# Reading and storing values from .OBJ files using C++

Tags: c++, .obj

First, sorry for bad english. Well, I'm trying read the values of a .OBJ file (see [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!AYVSTSyD!GI40jRZj4OMoLH4GDyyLWQvpVCV5t0HmKLjWtztLJdc)) and storing them in variables using this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
string v, valuesX[8], valuesY[8], valuesZ[8];
int n = 0;

ifstream myfile ("cubo.obj");
while(!myfile.eof())
{
    getline (myfile,line);
    if (line[0] == 'v')
    {
        myfile >> v >> valuesX[n]>> valuesY[n]>> valuesZ[n];
        cout << valuesX[n] << "\t" << valuesY[n] << "\t" << valuesZ[n] << endl;
        n++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The file it's only a simple cube, exported by Blender. I expected him to show me all lines beginning with "v", but the result presents only the odd "v" lines. When I read directly the value of the variable "line", the result is the same. However, when I remove the line that assigns values ​​to variables "value" and read the variable "line" directly, the program works perfectly. Anyone know explain to me what is happening? Why the program is ignoring the even lines?

Comment: The problem is that `getline` reads a line and then you read the next line when you do `myfile >> v >> valuesX[n]>> valuesY[n]>> valuesZ[n];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you read one line with:

```
getline (myfile,line);
```

and then if the line has `v` in the first position you read another line with this statement:

```
myfile >> v >> valuesX[n]>> valuesY[n]>> valuesZ[n];
```

but you do not process the previous line read in with the `getline` so you will lose that line. One possible solution is to process each `line` that matches using `istringstraeam`:

```
std::istringstream iss( line );
iss >> v >> valuesX[n]>> valuesY[n]>> valuesZ[n];
```

Comment: Well I was suspecting! For my tests, I suspected that this command was something like that, just did not know how, but you explained well and your solution worked! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

You're reading 2 lines per loop:

**First time:**

```
getline(myfile, line);
```

**Second time:**

```
myfile >> v >> valuesX[n] >> valuesY[n] >> valuesZ[n];
```

So you're discarding half your data.

**Solution:** Try using the `ifstream::peek` function to see if a line begins with a `'v'`, then you would read all the values into your variables.

Comment: or leave the getline and do something like 
`std::stringstream lineStream;
lineStream<<line;`
and then just switch `myfile` to `lineStream` in the part that caused the second read.

Comment: The problem is this, but I thought it best to use "istringstraeam" even. Anyway, thank you! :D